# How to write VS Code tasks that does not waits for process to finish?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I want to make a task which will build a project and open resulting pdf-file in pdf viewer:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "type": "shell",
        "command": "make",
    },
    {
        "label": "Build and View",
        "type": "process",
        "command": "evince",
        "args": [
            "_build/document.pdf"
        ],
        "dependsOn": ["Build"],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

But it makes VS Code wait until pdf viewer process exists. Which is not what I want. In addition when running task again I get

[image]